# Mysql select rows from multiple tables in specific order

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have 2 tables in a mysql database ("comments" and "replies")

They have the schemas:

```
comments: id,userId,text
replies: id,userId,commentId,text
```

I need a mysql query that will fetch all comments from the comment table, and after each comment, the corresponding replies from the replies table...

so if we had:  `[comment 1] and [comment 2] in the comments table, and [reply 1] (to comment 1) and [reply 2] (to comment2)` in the replies table

then it would return:

```
    [comment 1]
    [reply 1]
    [comment 2]
    [reply 2]
```

Comment: You might want to play around with `group_concat`.

Comment: @Solarflare - they way I understand the question Daniel wants to get the replies in rows following the comments - group_concat would be used create a single column with all replies in it.

Comment: @PaulF yes, I think you are right, I misread that. Your union solution should work.

Comment: @PaulF  Thats right, the reason i am trying to get them in the correct sorted order is to avoid having to use one query per comment to fetch the replies... as in, i could fetch all comments simply by SELECT * FROM comments, but then i would have to run a SELECT * FROM replies WHERE commentId=[id from comment] for each comment....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to join the two tables & then order based on the commentID & replyID for multiple replies.

In the following I have added a dummy replyID of 0 for the original comment. The tables are joined using UNION ALL. Note that I have renamed the original id column of the comments table & reply id so they do not clash.

```
SELECT id commentID, userID, text, 0 replyID FROM test.comments
UNION ALL
SELECT commentID, userID, text, id replyID FROM test.replies
ORDER BY commentID, replyID;
```

Comment: Correct answer, only this is not called "joining", but "combining result sets".

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - of course you are right - just my bad choice of words when explaining my answer.